# Windows 10 - Clearing Event Logs in CMD batch script with all output running on same line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script which part of it is clearing the Event logs of Windows 10.
I would like to see the output of the following **wevtutil.exe** command, but output just on a single line (overwriting each line) instead of many multiple lines.

I know about the ANSI Escape Sequences `ESC[1FESC[0J` and `ESC[1A` which can overwrite a previous line (The **ESC** char is ALT+027 and can be seen in Notepad++), but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that with the `wevtutil.exe el` command. It still outputs each line one after the other.
Here's what I tried (running in CMD with admin rights):

```
@echo off
SET OverwriteLine=ESC[1FESC[0J
echo Making sure the variable OverwriteLine actually works. This is line 1.
echo %OverwriteLine%If you see this line instead of line 1, OverwriteLine works.
echo Great, now let^'s see if it works for the "wevtutil.exe cl" command
pause
echo Clearing Event logs...
@echo on
for /F "tokens=*" %%E in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO echo %OverwriteLine% | wevtutil.exe cl "%%E"
pause
```

I know this can be done via Powershell's `$host.ui.RawUI.CursorPosition`, but I need a solution for CMD/BAT.

Comment: You wouldn't use the VT100 escape code with the `wevutil.exe el` command, that simply provides the enumeration strings for the `do` portion, which provides the output. You would therefore use that VT100 sequence with the `wevtutil.exe cl "%%E"` command(s). Once you've tried that, if it doesn't work as written and intended, post the code you've tried and explain the issue it is exhibiting. We are not here to simply provide you with the answer, we are here to help you to fix a single, specific is replicable issue with your submitted code. Your submitted code does not currently exhibit an issue!

Comment: I have revised the code in the post with an example of what I tried. Please see if you can help with the syntax to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

As we deal with a single specific issue per question, and your main one appears to be with the implementation of the VT100 sequences, here is a commented example using a completely different for loop just for demonstration of the technique.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Rem Create a variable to use as the escape character
For /F %%G In ('Echo Prompt $E ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe') Do Set "\x1b=%%G"
Rem This is a static line included to demonstrate that it is unaffected
Echo(Output
Rem Turns off the cursor and removes a stray new line caused by Echo
Echo(%\x1b%[?25l%\x1b%[1A
Rem For loop example
For /L %%G In (1,1,8) Do (
    Rem Clears to the beginning of the line, prints the output, and moves up a line
    Echo(%\x1b%[1KLine %%G%\x1b%[1A
    Rem Creates a short delay between output lines to see the effect
    %SystemRoot%\System32\PATHPING.EXE 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 650 1>NUL
)
Rem Turns on the cursor again
Echo(%\x1b%[?25h
Pause
```

Comment: Thanks...I've managed to come up with a solution!

Comment: Yes, your code works. It outputs text on the same line with the delay specified with the PATHPING command. I understood your code perfectly. But eventually, it turned out I just needed to adjust my syntax a little using the same escape codes I started with.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the solution:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%E in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (wevtutil.exe cl "%%E" | echo <ESC>[1F<ESC>[0KClearing %%E)
```

### Explanation/Notes:

- **< ESC>** means the special `ESC` escape code sequence. You can generate this char by typing **ALT+027** in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) if you're editing your code in there, or generate it at runtime using the FOR loop that **Compo** mentioned.
- We move the cursor to the beginning of the previous line with **`ESC`[1F**.
- We then clear from the cursor to the end of the line with **`ESC`[0K**.
- Clearing the Windows event logs requires running the CMD script with Administrator rights.
- Expect some event logs to fail. The failed ones will remain on the screen, each on a new line (which might become handy). If you don't want to see any failures, just add **2>nul** : `DO (wevtutil.exe cl "%%E" 2>nul | echo <ESC>[1F<ESC>[0KClearing %%E)`

You can learn more about escape codes [here](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797).